# In GNU Radio Companion, what is the Grey Frequency tab on the Signal Source block?

Tags: gnuradio-companion

How do you use the grey tab labelled "freq" on the left side of the signal source block? What data type does that accept and how can I generate signals of that type?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is you can set the frequency of the signal using a message. See https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-qtgui/examples/test_qtgui_msg.grc for an example.

If you haven't already done so, look at our Tutorials too. https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Tutorials